# What is Rainbow (not the CMS)

Tags: performance, sql, tools, orm, linq

I was reading this excellent [blog article](http://samsaffron.com/archive/2011/05/02/A+day+in+the+life+of+a+slow+page+at+Stack+Overflow)  regarding speeding up the badge page and in the last comment the author [waffles (a.k.a Sam Saffron)](http://stackexchange.com/users/9321/waffles) mentions these tools:

> dapper and a bunch of custom helpers like rainbow, sql builder etc

[Dapper](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/) and [sql builder](http://sqlobject.org/SQLBuilder.html) was easy to look up but rainbow keeps pointing me to a CMS, can someone please point me to the real source? Thanks.

*Obviously the architecture of these [SE] sites is uber cool and ultra fast so no comments on that thanks.*

Comment: Notice I didn't put the `Ponies` tag:)

Comment: Try, if you dare... ;P

Comment: @YannisRizos lol, users with less than 300 reputation can't create new tags. The tag 'ponies' is new. Try using an existing tag instead.

Comment: What?! We don't already have [ponies]? We used to have [rain-dance], [ponies] isn't that bad comparing...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Author apparently refers to **Dapper.Rainbow** micro-ORM used in Stack Exchange Data Explorer.

- Project home page at NuGet Gallery - http://nuget.org/packages/Dapper.Rainbow

> Trivial micro-orm implemented on Dapper, provides with CRUD helpers.
>   ...
>   The implementation was extracted from http://data.stackexchange.com source at: http://code.google.com/p/stack-exchange-data-explorer/ .
>   
>   **Data explorer uses "Rainbow" exclusively for all database access.**
>   ...
>
> #### Authors
>
> [Sam Saffron](http://nuget.org/packages?q=Sam%20Saffron)
>   ...